# AsynchronousFileChannel for a file in a jar

Tags: java, spring, classpath, nio, channel

Is there a way to open an `AsynchronousFileChannel` for a file stored in a jar on the classpath?

If I try creating a `Path` directly, I get `FileSystemNotFoundException`.
If I create the file system first:

```
URI uri = ...; //get the URI of a file in a jar
String[] array = uri.toString().split("!");
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create(array[0]), Collections.emptyMap());
Path path = fs.getPath(array[1]);
AsynchronousFileChannel ch = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(path);
```

It explodes with `UnsupportedOperationException` :(

Is there any way to achieve this?

My project is Spring (and using `ClassPathResource` for this), so a Spring specific solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zip file system provider in the JDK does not support asynchronous I/O so this is why UOE is throw.